# How to connect to localhost/ html form directing to PHP code

Tags: php, html, mysql, localhost

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to my localhost in order to run some php updating a local mysql server. Below is my html code containing the form, and the php im running. When i submit my form, it directs me to my php file in browser (as code). Is that supposed to happen? On top of that, my SQL database is not being updated.

test_2232.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="update_2232.php" method="post">
    <h3>Code:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="officeCode">
    <h3>Name:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

update_2232.php:

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO office (officeCode, name)
VALUES ('601', 'Boora')");
?>
```

Thanks for any tips

Comment: If you see your update.php file with the PHP code in it in the browser it means your environment is not parsing it as PHP. PHP isn't enabled or properly configured so its also not going to do the work of connecting to your db.

Comment: haven't you forgot `$officeCode = $_POST['officeCode'];` and `$name = $_POST['name'];`?

Comment: Cheers guys, it was both of those issues, thanks :) just pretty new to PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php

    $officecode=$_POST['officeCode'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
     mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_query($connect,"INSERT INTO office (officeCode, name)
    VALUES ('$officecode', '$name')");

?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$officecode=$_POST['officeCode'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
 mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') or die(mysqli_error()); 
 mysqli_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO office (officeCode, name)
VALUES ('$officecode', '$name')");
?>
```

You can't use both mysql and mysqli together.